# Access denied to logo link image with a non admin user

Tags: 7

I must solve some bugs in a 'big' drupal 7 website. I have a strange behaviour, if I connect to the website as an admin the logo image appears correctly. But if I connect with a non-admin user, the logo doesn't appears, the url path go to a denied access drupal page.

Do you have any idea what module/custom-code can do that ?

Comment: How this logo output in template - as $logo variable or another way? Show the code pls.

Comment: The logo output in the template seems standard (but its in a custom template). I haven't any problem for show some code, but I haven't any ideas where is the problem, so...I don't know which code shows haha . In the page.tpl.php on the custom template, the logo output is : <?php if ($logo): ?>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a>
      <?php else: ?>

Comment: Try to set garland theme and check, if logo will work. If logo will work-check your theme's template.php for preprocess functions :  for ex. template_preprocess_page